# Where clause not working in stored procedure, when working outside of it

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

We built a piece of dynamic sql that generates a wide view from data in long format. Seen here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `selectPivotedTermpoints`(studyid varchar(300))
BEGIN

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000000;
SET @psql = NULL;
SET @finalSQL = NULL;
SET @StudyID = studyid;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN terminate = ''', REPLACE(Terminate,'''', ''''''), ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `', REPLACE(Terminate,'''', ''), '`')
  ) INTO @psql
FROM Dashboard
WHERE studyid = @StudyID
  AND completion_status = 'terminate';

SET @finalSQL = CONCAT('
SELECT Sample_provider as Provider,
       completion_status as `Status`,',
       @psql,'
FROM   Dashboard
WHERE studyid = ''', @StudyID, '''
  AND completion_status = ''terminate''
GROUP  BY Sample_provider');

SELECT @finalSQL;
PREPARE stmt FROM @finalSQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

When the sql is run as a query,(from SET to DEALLOCATE)setting @StudyID manually, we return a table with only the columns for that specific study(distinct Terminate as columns for only that study), however when the query is turned into a stored procedure and run it is generating a table with columns for all studies(all distinct Terminate as columns).

It appears that the first where clause (in the select group_concat) is being ignored when run as a stored procedure, but this is not the case when run as a simple query.

Stored procedure call:

```
selectPivotedTermpoints('bhp_03a');
```

Does anyone know why this is the case and / or how I can correct the issue?

Comment: Stored Proc header? I.E. How are it's parameters defined? And what is the call being made to it?

Comment: Updated the question with this information, meant to have it in the first place

Comment: Can you show some sample data, and the desired vs. actual results? Also, what does `@finalSQL` look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I helped someone with a similar issue recently in another question; it confused us for quite a while. Change the parameter name to something else, I am guessing that `WHERE` is using it instead of the field in the table.

*(You might be able to get away with `Dashboard.studyid` as well, but changing the parameter name will cause less confusion; and I am not positive how the query in @finalSQL would behave either.)*

Comment: This was perfect, thanks! It's always something obvious yet not.

Comment: Absolutely insane 
Helped!